# d aGetting error while connecting to Postgres via dev c++

Tags: postgresql, dev-c++

I am trying to get connected to Postgres database via Dev-c++ (Windows application and not console) for executing queries, but I am continuously getting errors.

I went through the following link: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm
and added the below code to that of mine:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <pqxx/pqxx> 

     using namespace std;
     using namespace pqxx;

     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     {
      try{
          connection C("dbname=testdb user=postgres password=cohondob \
          hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
          if (C.is_open()) {
          cout << "Opened database successfully: " << C.dbname() << endl;
          } else {
          cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
          return 1;
           }
        C.disconnect ();
        }catch (const std::exception &e){
        cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
        }
        }
```

But got error stating: 
'No such file or directory
 #include  
Compilation terminated'

Please, Can anyone help me get through this?
is there any other possible way to get connected?